# File Exists not working in POJO class

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, pojo

I have a class which is having only getters and setters.

```
class MyObject
{
        private string imageName;       
        public string MyImageName
        {
            get 
            {
                if (!File.Exists("/Data/Images/" + imageName+ ".png"))
                {
                    imageName= "/Data/Images/" + imageName+ "~phone.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    imageName= "/Data/Images/" + imageName+ ".png";
                }
                return imageName;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.imageName && value != null)
                {
                    imageName= value;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Here always it will return path as `imageName= "/Data/Images/" + imageName+ "~phone.png";`, its not entering the else part at all.

I am working on WP8 application.

Why so ? what am i doing wrong here ?

**EDIT 1**

I am checking for file existance in POJO because i have passed this `MyObject` as `itemSource to List box`.

**EDIT 2**

I have these images in a folder named Data/Images in my application.

**EDIT 3**

I have the MyObject already with the values, like imageName is already set, say `abc` is set as imageName.Now when i trying to get imageName the image can be of two types like `abc.png or abc~phone.png` so it should check if either of them is present and return that.

Comment: Never concatenate strings to generate path. use `Path.Combine`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel sorry i didnt get you  ?

Comment: Did you set the MyImageName property (and its backfield imagename) to something before asking if the file exists?

Comment: If you're using WP8, shouldn't you be using the Isolated Storage API? It's not clear where you want this code to be looking...

Comment: So, apart from the correct comment of @JonSkeet how do you expect that concatenating an empty string to your path gives back something meaningful?

Comment: @Steve No when i try to debug that , the imageName is already set and i just want to get the path thats it,

Comment: @Goofy playing with file paths without [Path class](http://www.dotnetperls.com/path) is error prone. Use methods of path class.

Comment: It will be useful to see how do you declare, initialize and use an instance of this class.

Comment: As an aside, it's not a POJO given that it's not Java. Classes like this in the CLR are sometimes called POCOs... but given the interaction with the file system, I don't think I'd call it a POCO either.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself:

It was the problem with path;

```
if (!File.Exists("/Data/Images/" + imageName+ ".png")) 

should be

if (!File.Exists("Data/Images/" + imageName+ ".png"))
```